# Take command line arguments on java execution

Tags: java, terminal

I'm trying to make a program that can run with a gui or in a terminal only mode with no gui. How could I make it so that when the program is called in the terminal, the user adds an argument to determine whether to run with a gui or not?

By entering something like this when they start my program: `java myprogram -Nogui`

Answer (score 1):

In the main method of your java program, just check if any of the arguments passed  (the `String[]` parameter) are the one you are looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean useGui = true;
    for(String arg : args) if(arg.equals("-Nogui") useGui = false;
    // Now check `useGui` to see if a GUI should be displayed or not
}
```

Comment: That was much simpler than I thought it would be, thanks!